# Is there a fix when trying to display a single item from an api using httpClient and angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to pull a single data item from this "
https://api.icndb.com" api. I am using httpClient and a service component in angular to pull the data but for some reason I can't display the data. I used console log to display the response but outputs undefined.

This is App.component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Jokes } from './jokes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Jokes;

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {}

  title = 'Dry jokes';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadJokes();
  }

  loadJokes() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-debugger
    this.apiService.getJokes().subscribe((res: Jokes) => {this.data = res; });
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

This is ApiService

```
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Observable,
  throwError,
  ObservableInput
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  retry,
  catchError
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Jokes } from './jokes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  url = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random';

 getJokes() {
   return this.http.get<Jokes>(this.url).pipe(retry(1), 
     catchError(this.errorHandl));
 }

 errorHandl(error) {
   let errorMessage = '';
   if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
     // Get client-side erro
     errorMessage = error.error.message;
   } else {
     // Get server-side error
     errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
   }
   console.log(errorMessage);
   return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

This is app.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    {{title}}
  </h1>
  <p ngFor* ="let item of data">
    {{data?.jokes}}
  </p>
</div>
```

```
export class Jokes {
  id: number;
  joke: string;
}
```

When I try to use ng-for to iterate through, I get this error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: "console.log(this.data);" will execute before the subscribe result; put a console log before "this.data = res;"

Comment: That did not work! I am still getting "defined"

Comment: Your code does not contain a "ngFor". Data is not an array; it should be declared as Jokes[].

Answer (score 0):

not seeing an ngFor in your code, but you can only use ngFor on arrays, and the response data here is not an array.  The reason your data isn't showing in this case is because you're not accessing the correct property:

```
{{data?.value.joke}}
```

inspecting the returned object, it's relevant structure is

```
{
  success: string;
  value: {
    id: number;
    joke: string;
    category: string[];
  }
}
```

Comment: So how would I change the output to an array?